# how to change background color and background image with multiple color and multiple image on one click div through jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#block").click(function(){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("greenDiv")) {
            $(this).addClass("greenDiv");
      $("#block12").hide('fast');
        } /* else {
          $("#block12").hide('fast');
        } */
    });


  $(function(){
    $("#block").hover(function(){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("greenDiv1")) {
            $(this).addClass("greenDiv1");
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("greenDiv1");
        }
    });

});

$("#block12").click(function(){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("greenDiv12")) {
            $(this).addClass("greenDiv12");
       $("#block").hide('fast');
        } /* else {
          $("#block").hide('fast');
        } */
    });


  $(function(){
    $("#block12").hover(function(){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("greenDiv123")) {
            $(this).addClass("greenDiv123");
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass("greenDiv123");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to add a similar event but to multiple elements with some common property,** then you can use something like the line below. This checks for all elements with an `id` that starts with `^=` the string `block`.

```
    $("*[id^=block]").click(function() { ... });
```

**You can then change the parameters of the individual element that was clicked** using any of the following:

```
$(this).toggleClass("...") // toggle a class
$(this).attr("name", "newvalue") // Change name of element to 'newvalue', can be used on any attribute
```

**If you want to change multiple elements in a different way, with a similar characteristic then use the multiple selector with an `.each()` function.** The code below cycles from each element with an `id` that starts with `block` and appends a '.' to the div, you can do anything you want within that code block.

```
$("*[id^=block]").each(function() {
  $(this).append(".");
});
```

**If you want to do the same thing to all elements with a common selector**, then you can combine the action into a single line, like the following line that toggles the class 'blue-text' to all elements with an `id` starting with block.

```
$("*[id^=block]").toggleClass("blue-text");
```

---

## Demo

```js
// add click event to any item with an ID that starts with block
$("*[id^=block]").click(function() {

  // Toggle a class on clicked element (better than your if statements checking if it hasClass
  $(this).toggleClass("greenDiv");

  // Do something to all divs with matching id
  // Just adding a dot to the text
  $("*[id^=block]").each(function() {
    $(this).append(".");
  });


});

// Add click event to blue button
$("#blue").click( function() {

  // Toggle blue-text class for all elements that match selector
  $("*[id^=block]").toggleClass("blue-text");
  
});
```

```css
.greenDiv {
  color: green !important;
}

.blue-text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block11">11</div>
<div id="block12">12</div>
<div id="block13">13</div>
<div id="block14">14</div>


<button id="blue">Blue Text</button>
```

Comment: change multiple colors and also multiple images clicking by one by one through diff “id” using one div in jquery how can i do that #Oliver Trampleasure